# How can we impersonate a user in Identity Server 4

Tags: identityserver4, impersonation, sitecore9

I have a requirement where Customer care people login with their credentials and have to impersonate the actual users.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allow supporter to sign in as another user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56274215/allow-supporter-to-sign-in-as-another-user)

Answer (score 0):

You can implement service account flow for same. Using it you can get token of respective client with all allowed scopes to client (This client has all the scope required to access customer care resource).